# Getting Json to a model object

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I need to get Json to my model but i have problems(i am beginner).

my model

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1c2e88cb83cbeace6f34

and i need to do getting json to my model 
and i need json->to model convertion

and i use web service for getting json
and how can i implement object list of jobs to my model

controller

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c526483b29be0b198bca

i need objects to edit some details and i want to re convert to Json

my opinion is this
i am open new ideas

Thanks...

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking here. It's also probably really broad. Could you update to ask some narrower/more specific questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have nearly everything you need there.  To convert `builds` in the JSON to a list of `Build`, you'd do this:

```
  val js: JsValue = response.json
  (js \ "builds").as[List[Build]]
```

To modify a field, you can do, for example:

```
val build = builds.head // get the first build
val modifiedBuild = build.copy(name = "new name")
```

Then to convert that back to being JSON:

```
Json.toJson(mp)
```